# Sound measurement settings

Tags: sound

Not sure it's a 100% appropriate forum, but we're having a project at school in which we faff around with noise measurements. The problem is we haven't really been given proper instructions on how to use the meters - just a slip listing some settings. I was wondering if anyone could help me interpret it:

"1) RMS, fast, Leq
2) Peak, Imp, SPL
3) RMS, Slow, SPL"

We were instructed to measure the noise level in various enviroments (silence, extreme noise, somewhere inbetween for example a class room) using both A- and C-filters, but not really when to use what setting, or how to interpret the results.

For example, when using setting #2, this meter told me that when my daughter dropped a crayon about a meter away, she emitted an 80dB noise. It doesn't even seem reasonable to me. Maybe there's something about the SPL setting that I'm missing?

Can anyone help me with deciphering the instructions?

Comment: Do you have a link to the meter you are using?

Comment: It is a Brüel & Kjaer Type 2230.

Comment: I know you asked this question a long time ago, but you might be interested in some advice. I am not familiar with the meter you are using, but when we calibrate home theater systems, especially in the subwoofer region, the meters we use are always set to " c weighting" and "slow"

Comment: Mentioning some rationale behind why you find those settings best would be good. Even if just based on experience it would be better to include some of the pros and cons you've found to the various options.